How to properly inform SVN about files moved outside of SVN control in Visual Studio?
I'm using Visual Studio 2019 with a Subversion repository. Sometimes files need to be moved to new locations through Visual Studio, but since SVN is not integrated into the IDE, it's not aware of these moves.
I've created a batch script that can detect moved files and their new locations:
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:: Check if the SVN directory path is provided
if "%1"=="" (
    echo Please provide the path to the SVN repository.
    echo Usage: %~nx0 path\to\svn\repository
    exit /b 1
)
:: Initialize variables
set repo_path=%1
pushd "%repo_path%"
:: Get and display list of missing files from SVN status
echo Filename                   Old Path                    New Path
echo ========                   =========                   =========
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%f in ('svn status "%repo_path%" ^| findstr "^! "') do (
    set "found=0"
    set "new_path=DELETED"
    for /f "delims=" %%p in ('dir /s /b "%%~nxf" 2^>nul') do (
        if not "%%p"=="!repo_path!\%%f" (
            set "found=1"
            set "new_path=%%p"
            set "new_path=!new_path:%CD%\=!"
        )
    )
    echo %%~nxf                 %%f                 !new_path!
)
popd
endlocal

When I run this script, it correctly identifies files that SVN shows with ! status and finds their new locations. For example:
Filename                   Old Path                    New Path
========                   =========                   =========
LoggingModel.cs           Models\LoggingModel.cs      Models\Logging\LoggingModel.cs
MainWindowModel.cs        Models\MainWindowModel.cs   Models\Main\MainWindowModel.cs

I tried using svn move commands like:
svn move Models/LoggingModel.cs Models/Logging/LoggingModel.cs

But I get the error:

svn: E155010: Path 'C:\path\to\repo\Models\Logging\LoggingModel.cs' is not a directory

And when trying:
svn move Models/LoggingModel.cs Models/Logging/

I get:

svn: E150002: Path 'C:\path\to\repo\Models\Logging\LoggingModel.cs' already exists as unversioned node

What is the correct SVN command sequence to:

Tell SVN about the new location of these files
Preserve their history
Handle the fact that the files are already physically in their new locations

I want to expand my batch script to automatically handle this once I know the correct SVN commands to use.
P.S.1. Installing VisualSVN for Visual Studio 2019 extension now moving files by drag and drop or cut and paste, Subversion sees those files as deleted and added, which is OK if you do not care about the history of those files. But I believe there should be a better solution. For example from this page I might be able to move the files back to their old location and then use svn move to "re-move" them back to the new location in a proper way.
P.S.2. Posted a solution here on GitHub.

Don't move files through your IDE and you won't have a problem at all. As for the svn move command, have you tried the --force option?

@Friedrich I have to use the IDE otherwise updating the whole code manually becomes very difficult!

Concerning your PS: did you verify that moving with VisualSVN does actually lose history? Because I don't think it does.

@Friedrich Moving or copying in Visual Studio when the VisualSVN plug-in is active properly translates these operations to SVN and preserves history as if the operation was performed using proper svn commands.

@Friedrich sorry for my ignorance, but I don't know how to check if the history is retained. All I see is that when I do svn status it shows D for the old path and A for the new paths. And I just interpreted that as deleted and added.

The ultimate test is to commit the file after the move and take a look at its svn log. If it has only one entry saying it was newly added, there's no history. If the log goes further back, you have history. Ideally, do your experiments on a toy repo.

@Friedrich so assuming I want to use the above cmd batch instead of the VisualSVN plugin (e.g., when using another editor/IDE that doesn't have a proper Subversion integration), what is the canonical way to inform svn of the relocation? is there a command built-into svn, or moving the file back to the old location and then using svn move is the only option?

Taking all your restrictions into account, I'm not aware of any other solution than to move it back and svn move it forth. The solution to your more general question is to use the proper tool for each job. Use svn, TortoiseSVN or VisualSVN for interactions with Subversion. You are reinventing the wheel.

@Friedrich I just added an answer below  could you be kind to test it and help me know if this works properly or not?

I'm afraid I can't. Let's put aside that this is beyond the scope of this site and that I don't want to be responsible for the correctness of your answer. It's plain and simple that I don't have access to a Windows machine with VS or Subversion. I'll leave it to the community to verify and rate your answer.

@Friedrich It would be great if we could have something like "peer review request" on these forums. Other than that, thanks for your kind support.

The VisualSVN plugin properly records moves as Copy + Delete operations and you can check this by examining local changes. The status of the target file will say Added (+) Moved from …, so the information about the actual move is recorded in SVN.
Local uncommitted change (svn update):
PS C:\MyTest\ConsoleApp> svn status
M       ConsoleApp2.csproj
A  +    NewFolder\Program.cs
        > moved from Program.cs
D       Program.cs
        > moved to NewFolder\Program.cs

Details of the commit (svn log -r 3 -v):
r3 MyUsername | 2024-11-12 16:08:48 +0800 (Tue, 12 Nov 2024) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/ConsoleApp2.csproj
   A /trunk/NewFolder/Program.cs (from /trunk/Program.cs:2)
   D /trunk/Program.cs

And the details from ‘Show Changes’:




So if I am understanding you correctly the Subversion's move (mv, rename, ren) is just a combination of delete (del, remove, rm) and add, right?

so practically I could add svn del oldPath followed by svn add newPath to the cmd batch and it should work, true?

@FoadS.Farimani sorry, I haven’t reviewed the batch script from your question and I’m not entirely sure what task you want to complete. But manually running svn delete followed by svn add won’t make SVN automatically record the move.

@FoadS.Farimani to make it totally clear, running svn delete and svn add is not the same as svn move. A move will preserve history while the other two commands won't.

Now I am genuinely confused again. Imagine, for what ever reason, one doesn't want to install the Visual SVN plugin, then how should the cmd batch script be completed for a proper recognition of the files relocation by svn? all I could think of o far is to move the files back to their location, and then use svn move to relocate them to the indented new directory. But this seems risky, specially given that the old folders might no longer exist. We might end-up cluttering the code base, the least.

@Friedrich how do you know if one has used svn move or a combination of svn delete and svn add? How do you check the difference? sorry if I am too much of a subversion noob.

Here's a workaround I developed - it's not a canonical solution but it worked for my use case. The idea is to temporarily move files back to their original locations and then use svn move to relocate them properly.
Warning: This approach has limitations:

Doesn't handle deleted source folders
Could potentially create issues if interrupted mid-process
Should be used with caution on production code

Here's the minimal working example (svn_move_files.bat):
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set repo_path=%1
pushd "%repo_path%"

for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%f in ('svn status "%repo_path%" ^| findstr "^! "') do (
    for /f "delims=" %%p in ('dir /s /b "%%~nxf" 2^>nul') do (
        if not "%%p"=="!repo_path!\%%f" (
            set "new_path=%%p"
            set "new_path=!new_path:%CD%\=!"
            
            mkdir "%%~dpf" 2>nul
            move "!new_path!" "%%f"
            svn move "%%f" "!new_path!" --parents
        )
    )
)
popd
endlocal

I tested this with a simple scenario:

Created a basic WPF project:

DummyMoveTest/
    DummyMoveTest/
        MainWindow.xaml
        MainWindow.xaml.cs
        App.xaml
        // other standard files...


Moved files to MVVM structure in Visual Studio:

DummyMoveTest/
    DummyMoveTest/
        Views/
            MainWindow.xaml
            MainWindow.xaml.cs
        // other files...


svn status before running the script:

!       DummyMoveTest/DummyMoveTest/MainWindow.xaml
!       DummyMoveTest/DummyMoveTest/MainWindow.xaml.cs
?       DummyMoveTest/DummyMoveTest/Views


After running svn_move_files.bat .:

D       DummyMoveTest/DummyMoveTest/MainWindow.xaml
        > moved to DummyMoveTest/DummyMoveTest/Views/MainWindow.xaml
D       DummyMoveTest/DummyMoveTest/MainWindow.xaml.cs
        > moved to DummyMoveTest/DummyMoveTest/Views/MainWindow.xaml.cs
A       DummyMoveTest/DummyMoveTest/Views
A  +    DummyMoveTest/DummyMoveTest/Views/MainWindow.xaml
A  +    DummyMoveTest/DummyMoveTest/Views/MainWindow.xaml.cs

The files retain their history and can be committed normally. While this works, a proper SVN integration with Visual Studio would be a better long-term solution.
